# Java Properties.store is deleting other entries

Tags: java, configuration-files

I am trying to modify a config file in Java using Properties.  I try to modify two of the multiple entries like this:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
FileInputStream fin = null;
FileOutputStream fout = null;
fin  = new FileInputStream(mCallback.getConfFile());
fout  = new FileOutputStream(mCallback.getConfFile());
properties.load(fin);
properties.setProperty(Wrapper.GAME_PATH_KEY, (String)gamePathText.getText());
properties.setProperty(Wrapper.GAME_TYPE_KEY, (String)selectedGame.getSelectedItem());
properties.store(fout, null);
```

But when I check the file after the result I find out that the whole file was overwritten, leaving only these two entries. This is an android app though I guess it's not relevant to the problem here. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Mmmhhh ... try to `load` before create a new FileOutputStream with the same path. Probably FileOutputStream truncate the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous poster was kind of right, just not at the right place.

You need to open the `FileOutputStream` after you've loaded the properties otherwise it clears the file's content.

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
FileInputStream fin = null;
FileOutputStream fout = null;
fin  = new FileInputStream(mCallback.getConfFile());
// if fout was here, the file would be cleared and reading from it would produce no properties
properties.load(fin); 
properties.setProperty(Wrapper.GAME_PATH_KEY, (String)gamePathText.getText());
properties.setProperty(Wrapper.GAME_TYPE_KEY, (String)selectedGame.getSelectedItem());

fout  = new FileOutputStream(mCallback.getConfFile());

properties.store(fout, null);
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to read all properties and then modify the ones you want. After that you have to write all to file. You cannot do only an item modification. The Properties API doesn't provide that functionality to modify.

**Edit:**

Interchange these two statements-

```
fout  = new FileOutputStream(mCallback.getConfFile());
properties.load(fin);
```

You should load first before you create a file with the same name.

Comment: What you answered is describing what OP is currently doing. `load()` to read properties. `setProperty()` to change the ones they want. `store()` to write all the properties to file. This does not explain the problem or give a solution.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Edited. " I find out that the whole file was overwritten" in the question made me think that OP was expecting modification without creating a new file.

Comment: thank you guys for the answers.  Sajal im accepting the other because it says more clear that the issue was when to open the outputstream.  +1 to you wish coud upvote more

Comment: @quinestor I completely agree. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html):

> public void store(OutputStream out,
>                     String comments)
>              throws IOException
>
> > Writes this property list (key and element pairs) in this Properties table to the output > stream in a
> >     format suitable for loading into a Properties table using the
> >     load(InputStream) method.
> >
> > **Properties from the defaults table** of this
> >     Properties table (if any) are **not written** out by this method.
>
> This method outputs the comments, properties keys and values in the
>   same format as specified in store(Writer), with the following
>   differences:

So,  **Load** the data first,  then **set** the required data, then **store** it.

```
       Properties prop =new Properties();
       prop.load(new FileInputStream(filename));
       prop.setProperty(key, value);
       prop.store(new FileOutputStream(filename),null);
```